# Scrape from OG tags DOMCrawler - PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, domcrawler

I'm having trouble when scraping from this website. This code used to work but now it scrapes the wrong image. The purpose of this code is to scrape product image. But now it scrapes the logo of the website. here's a sample [product link](https://www.toryburch.com/en-us/clothing/sweaters/lurex-stripe-cardigan/85850.html?color=001) from that website.

```
protected function getImage(Crawler $crawler)
    {
        $image = null;
        if ($crawler->filter('meta[property="og:image"]')->count() > 0) {
            $image = $crawler->filter('meta[property="og:image"]')
                ->first()
                ->attr('content');
        }
    }
```

If it suppose to work as it did if I `dd($image)`, the output should be the src of product image. but now the output is always `'https://s7.toryburch.com/is/image/ToryBurch/medallion-navy@2x.1200x1200.jpg'`

I also tried modifying it to `filter()->eq() , filter()->siblings()`;
but non of them worked. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: When I request that URL you mentioned in my browser, the only thing it contains regarding og image, is `<meta property="og:image" content/>`. Have you verified that your crawler gets any different response, getting a meta tag that actually contains an image URL, to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe I just found out that it scraped randomly once the correct image but after another attempt , when I see the dom doc I couldn't see the tag I'm looking for. Is that means website using some kind of script? I refreshed dd($image) several times and got the correct image url. but it happens randomly